# On Android browser, clicking a link highlights the wrong link

Tags: android, browser

I have a responsive website that is doing some weird things on the Android browser.

For example, there's a table of links on http://mtganalytics.net/decks

I click a link and it goes to the correct URL. However, it highlights a link a few rows above it (the orange highlight, not the blue underline).

Plus, if I hold my finger a little bit longer over the link, I get the "Open in New Window" popup for the wrong link, the link above.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: did you find a fix? I also have this only on the Hebrew site.